# Preserve Eigen matrix from deleting after the function goes out of the scope

Tags: c++, arrays, eigen, vtk

My `Eigen::MatrixXf m` stores some data and I need to use this data in another array `vtkFloatArray`. In order to avoid copying the data I do:

```cpp
vtkNew<vtkFloatArray> array;    // `vtkNew` is a smart pointer class
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf m(2, 2);
    m << 1, 2, 3, 4;
    array->SetArray(m.data(), m.size(), 1);
}
// `array` must go on living and have access to the `.data()` pointer
```

The problem is that the `array` must live much longer than eigen matrix `m` lives but when the execution goes out of the scope it seems that `array` can't get values as they are removed (eigen matrix `m` is deleted when out of the scope).

It seems that I can dynamically allocate eigen matrix:

```cpp
vtkNew<vtkFloatArray> array;
{
    Eigen::MatrixXf* m = new Eigen::MatrixXf(2, 2);
    m << 1, 2, 3, 4;
    array->SetArray(m->data(), m->size(), 1);
}
// `array` must go on living and have access to the `.data()` pointer
```

Nevertheless [SetArray()](https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAOSDataArrayTemplate.html#a7f9c5547ac008ac745e6f8295ff869a6) has some options to save and delete array I suspect that I will get memory leak if I use this approach. Probably `std::shared_ptr<Eigen::MatrixXf> m` could help me but I'm not sure exactly as it should count references on matrix `m` and `vtkFloatArray` references to the `m.data()` pointer (though I maybe mistaken) and I will also get memory leak.

If someone knows how to keep my eigen matrix alive while `vtkFloatArray` is alive and do not get memory leak, please explain that.

Regards

Comment: Terminology: *It seems that I can create eigen matrix as a pointer* This is called dynamic allocation. If `m` is out of scope, `array` should also be out of scope, so unless `vtkNew` is playing silly games off-screen, the point should be moot. Wait a second. Are you returning `array` and that's how `m` goes out of scope? If so, the `m` is a dynamic allocation trick will definitely lead to a leak. Worse, does `array` take ownership of `m`'s data? That will probably go BOOM! somewhere down the line.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is "Can I transfer ownership of the backing data buffer from `Matrix` to some other object?" I'm no Eigen guru, but a quick search along those lines finds nothing.

Comment: @user4581301 hi, thank you for comment. I edited the question. I hope it will make my issue more transparent.. And yes, probably taking the ownership of an eigen data by buffer vtk array may solve the issue

Comment: Do you at all need the Eigen matrix? You don't in your snippet. If you do you could write a wrapper that holds both an Eigen matrix and an array and disposes of both of them in the destructor, in the right order.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica thabk you for the comment. I read data from disk to the eigen matrix that is it. I can't read these data directly to the vtk array. But thank you for the approach, I don't like it but if I don't find anything better then probably I will use your solution :)

Comment: You can't take away ownership of an `Eigen::Matrix` into a non-Eigen object (without hacking with Eigen's internals). Create a `vtkArray` somehow and access it via `Eigen::Map` if you must.

Comment: *"In order to avoid copying the data I do:"* That won't work. If you want to store the data into a `vtkArray` you need to copy it.

Comment: @RHertel: As long as they have the same layout, it can work with ```Map```.

Comment: @RL-S Did you try specifically with a `vtkPointer` / `vtkArray`? I remember that I once tried to transfer data to a `vtkArray` and did not succeed. I concluded that this was not possible without copying the data, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself. The [doc][1] says "Values are stored with fortran ordering", so that would be column-major as well (even though fortran is 1-based). If you create the ```vtkArray``` first, resize it correctly, and then access it via ```Eigen::Map```, it sounds like it should work. Do you remember what went wrong in your case?


  [1]: https://vtk.org/doc/release/6.2/html/classvtkDenseArray.html

Comment: Thank all for the comments, I guess I try @Peter-ReinstateMonica proposition (I will try to inherit from Eigen::Matrix and set there vtkArray and everytime the array is resized it is the user responsibility to update vtkArray number of points)

Comment: @Kerim if you find a working solution you can answer your own question for posterity. You may even get upvotes ,-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is based on @Peter-ReinstateMonica suggestion: create a wrapper class where both objects `vtkFloatArray` and `Eigen::MatrixXf` would reside and that would make possibe to control the lifetime of both these objects.

Let's call wrapper class `vtkEigenFloatArray` and let it be inherited from `vtkFloatArray`. As our wrapper class implicitely inherits `vtkObject` we should follow vtk's inheritance structure to make it usable within vtk (for example `vtkNew<vtkEigenFloatArray>`) while keeping pimp idiom (that is why you can see many vtk methods and macros within created class, this is done by analogy with `vtkFloatArray` source code).

We add `Eigen::MatrixXf* eigArr` member variable to our `vtkEigenFloatArray` class.

We also add the method `Eigen::MatrixXf* GetEigenArray()` that returns `Eigen::MatrixXf* eigArr` pointer and setter `void SetEigenArray(Eigen::MatrixXf* arr)` to make available to use the inner `Eigen::MatrixXf` object from ouside created class.

It worth to note that `vtkEigenFloatArray` and its protected `Eigen::MatrixXf* eigArr` object share the same buffer. It is set every time one calls `void UpdateEigenBuffer()` function. Moreover everytime when one resizes `Eigen::MatrixXf* eigArr` from outside the created class the function `void UpdateEigenBuffer()` **must be called** to update size of `vtkFloatArray`-inherited class.

Also user **must never externally delete** `Eigen::MatrixXf* eigArr` as it is deleted in `vtkEigenFloatArray`'s destructor.

**The drawback of proposed solution:**

When the main `vtkEigenFloatArray` object is deleted the pointer `Eigen::MatrixXf* eigArr` will not be equal to `nullptr`. Thus you cannot check whether `Eigen::MatrixXf* eigArr` is alive or not while you don't have holder `vtkEigenFloatArray` object.

```cpp
#include <vtkNew.h>
#include <vtkFloatArray.h>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>

class vtkEigenFloatArray : public vtkFloatArray
{
public:
  static vtkEigenFloatArray* New();
  vtkTypeMacro(vtkEigenFloatArray, vtkFloatArray);


  void PrintSelf(ostream& os, vtkIndent indent) override
  {
    this->RealSuperclass::PrintSelf(os, indent);
  }

  // This macro expands to the set of method declarations that
  // make up the interface of vtkAOSDataArrayTemplate, which is ignored
  // by the wrappers.
#if defined(__VTK_WRAP__) || defined(__WRAP_GCCXML__)
  vtkCreateWrappedArrayInterface(float);
#endif

  /**
   * A faster alternative to SafeDownCast for downcasting vtkAbstractArrays.
   */
  static vtkEigenFloatArray* FastDownCast(vtkAbstractArray* source)
  {
    return static_cast<vtkEigenFloatArray*>(Superclass::FastDownCast(source));
  }

  /**
   * Get the minimum data value in its native type.
   */
  static float GetDataTypeValueMin() { return VTK_FLOAT_MIN; }

  /**
   * Get the maximum data value in its native type.
   */
  static float GetDataTypeValueMax() { return VTK_FLOAT_MAX; }
  
  /**
   * Deletes previous pointer and sets new
   */
  void SetEigenArray(Eigen::MatrixXf* arr)
  {
    delete eigArr;
    eigArr = arr;
    UpdateEigenBuffer();
  }

  /**
   * Don't delete this pointer!
   */
  Eigen::MatrixXf* GetEigenArray()
  {
    return eigArr;
  }

  /**
   * Must be manually called every time Eigen::MatrixXf resized
   */
  void UpdateEigenBuffer()
  {
    this->SetArray(eigArr->data(), eigArr->size(), 1); // must be set to 1 or in destructor runtime error
  }

protected:
  vtkEigenFloatArray()
  {
    eigArr = new Eigen::MatrixXf();
  }

  ~vtkEigenFloatArray() override
  {
    delete eigArr;
    eigArr = nullptr;
  }
  
  Eigen::MatrixXf* eigArr;

private:
  typedef vtkAOSDataArrayTemplate<float> RealSuperclass;

  vtkEigenFloatArray(const vtkEigenFloatArray&) = delete;
  void operator=(const vtkEigenFloatArray&) = delete;

  friend class vtkNew<vtkEigenFloatArray>;
};

vtkStandardNewMacro(vtkEigenFloatArray);


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  /* General usage */
  vtkNew<vtkEigenFloatArray> arr;
  Eigen::MatrixXf* M = arr->GetEigenArray();
  M->resize(2, 2);
  *M << 1, 2, 3, 4;
  arr->UpdateEigenBuffer();

  std::cout << "Eigen M:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << *M << std::endl;

  std::cout << "VTK array:" << std::endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr->GetSize(); i++)
    std::cout << arr->GetValue(i) << std::endl;

  arr->Allocate(5);
  std::cout << "Eigen M:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << *M << std::endl;

  std::cout << "VTK array:" << std::endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr->GetSize(); i++)
    std::cout << arr->GetValue(i) << std::endl;

  /* Test `SetEigenArray` */
  Eigen::MatrixXf* MM = new Eigen::MatrixXf();
  MM->resize(2,2);
  *MM << 11, 22, 33, 44;

  arr->SetEigenArray(MM);

  std::cout << "Eigen MM:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << *MM << std::endl;

  std::cout << "VTK array:" << std::endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr->GetSize(); i++)
    std::cout << arr->GetValue(i) << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.